# if variable = then set variable to BASH

Tags: bash

How can I do something like this

```
   if [[ $variable = name ]]
  then
      $variable=fname
fi 
if [[ $variable = surname]]
  then
      $variable=sname
 fi
```

so change the value based on on result
as I have another web based script that sets variable to a user friendly name, but I need the script to change it to the correct one.
users will likely select multiple so i need it to change based on their choice

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you want to do. What values should the variable be set to, and based on what? What does "web based script" mean and does it have any bearing on your question?

Comment: basically the variable will be defined as one thing above and i need to change it before the script uses it

Comment: @Andy so what you mean is that the _name_ of the variable changes? This... is not a very good idea. There are much cleaner and better ways of approaching this such as using arrays for example. Can you give us some more details about what your script is doing and what you really need to achieve? (see [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101)).

Comment: @terdon so basically a customer uses a webpage and selects and option, example they select "Food" now that is pased to my script as $choice=Food, but my db value is groceries, so i need to say if the VARIABLE comes in as Food then change it to groceries before doing the lookup.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain this. Comments are easy to miss, hard to read and can be deleted without warning. Also explain i) why you don't just use the same variable names? ii) why the _name_ of the variable is important instead of its value (why don't you do something like `if [[ $variable1 = "food" ]]; then variable2="groceries"` or whatever).

Comment: Is it correct to say that, in your program, 1) your `variable` is initially assigned a value from a known set; 2) you also have a second set of values, which maps onto the first set; 3) you want to assign `variable` a value from the second set based on its _current_ value? E.g. `case "$variable" in curval) variable=newval;; othercurval) variable=othernewval;; esac`?

Answer (score 3):

Check your assignment syntax, you should not have a `$` there. `$` is for *expanding* variables.

```
# standard sh syntax
case $variable in
  (name)    variable=fname;;
  (surname) variable=sname;;
  (*)       printf >&2 '%s\n' "$variable not supported"; exit 1;;
esac
```

See also:

```
# ksh93/bash/zsh specific
typeset -A map=(
     [name]=fname
  [surname]=sname
)

variable=${map[$variable]?$variable not supported}
```

(beware that bash's associative arrays don't support the empty string as a key value).

In any case, you don't want to write a web CGI that takes user input as a shell script, as you'd be almost certain to introduced security vulnerabilities, especially if you're not a shell script expert.

Comment: To Further explain 

The variable can come in as multiple thins,
Example
$groceries=food or groceries=food,wine or even groceries=food,beer So multiple things
How can i change all those depending how they come in

Comment: @Andy, that sounds like a different question from the one currently stated. So you may want to ask a separate question. It also sounds you'd be better of using a proper programming language instead of a shell here, even if it's just `awk` even if the code for that programming language is embedded in a shell script.